# C++ TStringList AddObject

Tags: c++builder

In C++Builder, I wrote a simple class for storing a float.
Next, I tried to use the `AddObject` of `TStringList`.

Alas, the compiler gives 2 errors, pointing to the line with `AddObject`:

> Cannot convert 'TFloatNum' to 'TObject*'
>
> Type mismatch in parameter 'AObject' (wanted 'TObject*', got 'TFloatNum')

What am I doing wrong?

```
class TFloatNum {
  public:
    float N;
};

void __fastcall TForm1::btnAddClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  TFloatNum G;
  G.N = 75.5;
  StringList1->AddObject("a", G);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`AddObject()` expects a `TObject*` pointer, not a `TFloatNum` object instance.  `TFloatNum` does not derive from `TObject`, and you are not even storing a pointer anyway.

You need to dynamically allocate your `TFloatNum` object in order to store it correctly, and legally <sup>(1)</sup>.

If you don't derive `TFloatNum` from `TObject`, you will have to type-cast the resulting pointer (note - this will only work on non-ARC platforms - Windows and OSX - as ARC requires actual `TObject`-based object instances):

```
void __fastcall TForm1::btnAddClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  TFloatNum *G = new TFloatNum;
  G->N = 75.5;
  StringList1->AddObject("a", reinterpret_cast<TObject*>(G));
}
```

Then, to retrieve it later:

```
TFloatNum *G = reinterpret_cast<TFloatNum*>(StringList1->Objects[SomeIndex]);
...
```

And don't forget to `delete` object object when you are done using it:

```
delete G;
```

Alternatively, derive `TFloatNum` from `TObject`, then you don't need a type-cast when passing a `TFloatNum*` pointer to `AddObject()` <sup>(2)</sup>:

```
class TFloatNum : public TObject {
  public:
    float N;
};

void __fastcall TForm1::btnAddClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  TFloatNum *G = new TFloatNum;
  G->N = 75.5;
  StringList1->AddObject("a", G);
}
```

```
TFloatNum *G = static_cast<TFloatNum*>(StringList1->Objects[SomeIndex]);
...
delete G;
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup>: A `float` is 32 bits in size.  A pointer is 32 bits or 64 bits in size, depending on whether you compile for 32bit or 64bit systems.  You *could* take advantage of that fact and stuff the `TFloatNum` object directly inside the stored `TObject*` pointer itself without dynamically allocating the `TFloatNum` object (this only works on non-ARC platforms when `sizeof(TFloatNum) <= sizeof(void*)`):

```
class TFloatNum {
  public:
    float N;
};

void __fastcall TForm1::btnAddClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  TObject *obj = NULL;

  TFloatNum &G = reinterpret_cast<TFloatNum&>(obj);
  G.N = 75.5;

  StringList1->AddObject("a", obj);
}
```

```
TObject *obj = StringList1->Objects[SomeIndex];
TFloatNum &G = reinterpret_cast<TFloatNum&>(obj);
...
```

---

<sup>(2)</sup>: If you are using a relatively up-to-date version of C++Builder, `TStringList` has an `OwnsObjects` property that you can set to `true` to let the `TStringList` free `TObject`-based objects automatically for you.

---

That being said, a better solution is to not store `TFloatNum` objects directly in a `TStringList` in this manner to begin with.  Store them in a more suitable C++ container, such as `std::vector` or `std::list`.  Then, if you still need a `TStringList` for whatever reason, you can store indexes (`std::vector`) or `TFloatNum*` pointers (`std::list`) in the `TStringList` to help you get back to the `TFloatNum` objects when needed.

Using `std::vector<TFloatNum>`:

```
class TFloatNum {
  public:
    float N;
};

void __fastcall TForm1::btnAddClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  TFloatNum G;
  G.N = 75.5;
  SomeStdVector.push_back(G);

  StringList1->AddObject("a", reinterpret_cast<TObject*>(SomeStdVector.size()-1));
}
```

```
size_t FloatNumIndex = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(StringList1->Objects[SomeIndex]);
TFloatNum &G = SomeStdVector[FloatNumIndex];
...
```

Using `std::list<TFloatNum>`:

```
class TFloatNum {
  public:
    float N;
};

void __fastcall TForm1::btnAddClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  TFloatNum G;
  G.N = 75.5;
  SomeStdList.push_back(G);

  StringList1->AddObject("a", reinterpret_cast<TObject*>(&SomeStdList.back()));
}
```

```
TFloatNum *G = reinterpret_cast<TFloatNum*>(StringList1->Objects[SomeIndex]);
...
```

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you very much!